# Require with variable path in ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, assets, require

I'm trying to pass the `path` of `require` function in an app done with `ionic+vue`.

I read different `path` from a `json` and the `function` should be able to load different images based on this `path` using the `require` function in the image source.

```
<img :src="require(image)">
```

If I put the `path` as string it works without problems, but I need this path to change, so it has to be a variable.

Answer (score 1):

did you try using backticks for string interpolation so you can change the path by setting the `imagepath` variable?

```
<img :src=`require(${imagePath})`>
```

Comment: I've fix it using a the require inside a function, returning the value and using the resolved path from the src.